# Handle C# listener

Tags: c#, event-handling, win-universal-app, actionlistener, observer-pattern

I am trying to handle dialog buttons using an interface. I got this solution in android - java:

1) Declared one interface:

```
   public interface DialogPopUpListener {
    void onConfirmButtonClick();
    void onCancelButtonClick();
  }
```

2)Implemented dialog:

```
  public static void genericCreatePopUp(final Context context, final SimpleDialogPopUpListener listener) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage("Message");

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // do nothing to ignore autoclose
        }
    });


     builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
              // do nothing to ignore autoclose
        }
    });


    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    //Overriding the handler immediately after show POSITIVE
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onConfirmButtonClick("");
                dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    //Overriding the handler immediately after show NEGATIVE
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onCancelButtonClick();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

3) Call function to display dialog:

```
   GenericPopUpDialogSimple.genericCreatePopUp(context, new SimpleDialogPopUpListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfirmButtonClick(String editTxtInput) {
                        //handle positive button                            
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelButtonClick() {
                        //handle negative buton
                    }
                });
```

Now I wnt to migrate this functional in C#:

1) Declared the same interface;

2)Implemented dialog creation:

```
          public async void createDialog( SimpleDialogPopUpListener listener) {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Message", "Title");

        // Add positive command and set callback
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(btnOkTxt, UICommandInvokedHandler => {
            listener.onConfirmButtonClick();
        }) { Id = 0 });

        // Add negative command and set callback
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(btnCancelTxt, UICommandInvokedHandler => {
            listener.onCancelButtonClick();
        }) { Id = 1 });

        // Show the message dialog
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

3) **Here is the problem**, how can I call this method and override interface methods?

Answer (score 0):

In C# is a bit different because it does not support inline classes as Java. One solution is to define one class that implements your interface and use that class as parameter when call your method. So you'll have:

```
 public class MyImplementor : DialogPopUpListener {
    public void onConfirmButtonClick() {
        Debug.WriteLine("T  E  S  T --> ok");
        }

    public void onCancelButtonClick() {
        Debug.WriteLine("T  E  S  T --> cancel");
        }
    }
```

and you call your method:

```
     createDialog(new MyImplementor());
```